# 2018 Salary Survey: Compensation is Incomplete

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2018

So, the salary survey asked about salary, but neglected to ask about total compensation.  This is an oversight, because there will be a mix of compensation packages, including options, bonuses, reserved stock units, etc.  If those aren't taken into account, the results will be severely skewed.  By severely, let me give you an example: my total comp package - after vesting and including bonus - is easily 3x my base salary.  This will not be represented, as you didn't ask.

Comment: My compensation is incomplete, too - it's missing around $10k/year! (Seriously though, yeah this makes sense)

Comment: If I have 10k as official salary, but in fact receive 30k because of compensations, will I answer on question about my salary: "10k" ?

Comment: @Pekka웃  IMO it's *exactly* the opposite.. :-)

Comment: Could you post an example of how a total comp package can be "3x \[your\] base salary"? I believe you, I just want to learn some details -- an example, not personal details.

Comment: 30% bonus + ~1 year's annual salary's worth of options vesting + ~1 year's annual salary's worth of RSUs, would be one way of putting it.  But then throw in a 100% company's paying any deductible for healthcare, plus truly good healthcare.

Answer (score 5):

This is a tough issue we've gone back and forth with over the years on the survey, whether to try to ask developers to estimate the value of options or exercising them, to try to add this in or ask separately, etc. We decided this year to phrase the question as:

> What is your current gross salary (before taxes and deductions)?

The motivation to choose this wording was to have the most respondents understand this the most clearly. We specifically chose not to say "base salary" here so that developers whose compensation *is* complicated (for example, with bonuses) could respond with overall totals.

Comment: Might have been better worded as gross *compensation*, which includes bonuses and perks

Comment: That is a great suggestion and I am adding it to our notes for next year. We'll need to run it by non-native English speakers to understand its level of clarity.

Comment: Then, word it "with bonuses included" directly.

Comment: Just FYI, if you said "gross compensation" I would have no idea what that meant. Honestly I'm still not sure what a compensation package is. I get paid a salary and that's it (which seems pretty normal to me).

Comment: Problem with this: I know my base salary. It's one clear number on my paycheck. However, I don't know the sum of everything I get from the company. Especially the pension stuff is split into three parts and pretty complicated. I just take what I get and then I'll maybe see later, maybe only when I actually retire.

Comment: You could ask it as 2 or 3 questions: gross salary, bonus target %, options, reserved stock units. Last two could be yes/no questions, I suppose, or free text. You'd have to interpret the answers, but might be interesting.

Comment: The other thing: benefits are a major thing to have. Health benefits alone easily bump up the package by 30k for a really good package.